# What analysis can be done on #piegate photo to support it?

Tags: studio-lighting, professional, amateur, natural-lighting

Sarah Sanders posted this image in a tweet:
[image: I dont cook much these days, but managed this Chocolate Pecan Pie for Thanksgiving at the family farm!]

Some folks assumed that she didn't really bake the pie. Most of these folks cited either "that pie looks too perfect" as their evidence or cited nothing at all. She said that she baked it.

My question is: what analysis can be done on the image itself to support either claim? Is there evidence that it was shot with an iPhone? Or with a professional camera? How about the lighting?

Without saying anything about the *pie*, what can be said about the *photo*? Or maybe the answer is, "The photo itself provides no evidence either way."

Comment: This was answered here... https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/40080/did-the-white-house-press-secretary-lie-about-a-pie

Comment: If you view the ICC profile, it says its from an Apple device. Though it could have been taken on another camera, then just edited on an iPhone. Or a screenshot from the phone.

Comment: @vclaw - this should really probably be an answer.

Comment: The skeptics answer is indeed the best article I have seen. Thanks to Crazy Dino for that. I updated the answer to include @vclaw's idea.

Comment: What does "to support it" mean? What are we supporting? I'm in favor of pecan pie across all party lines.

Comment: @mattdm "support it" was shorthand for "provide evidence that this photo was shot by an amateur or provide evidence that this photo was shot by a professional". That seemed verbose for a subject, and I couldn't find a more elegant way to say it. Perhaps it annoyed folks that my phrasing implied it should support a particular conclusion, but that wasn't the intent.

Comment: Yeah, I'd suggest being more clear even if it takes more words, especially when the topic is controversial.

Comment: Followup: I'm loathe to link to linkbait sites like KnowYourMeme, but [the subject has been followed-up](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/sarah-huckabee-sanders-piegate) between Sarah Sanders and April D. Ryan (currently CNN political analyst). Takeaway: Sanders baked more pies for the press corps. With pictures. Legit.

Comment: vtc b/c Duplicate of [Skeptics.SE: Did the White House Press Secretary Lie about a Pie?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/40080/)

Answer (score -2):

From what I can tell, it seems like you can't say much more than this:

1. The photo isn't from any common stock photo sites. That is evidence the photo is legitimate.
2. You can determine the ICC Profile from the photo. I used this [online utility](http://exif.regex.info/exif.cgi). It indicates that the photo came from an Apple device. This is evidence that it's not a professional photo, so it's evidence that the photo is legitimate.

Thanks to @vclaw for the ICC Profile idea. I had never heard of such a thing.